# Asynchronously loading page (Not working properly) PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am currently on the settings page of my website and I am trying to load `Uhome.php`(The Homepage) asynchronously using **Ajax** and **PHP**  it works well but my only problem is when it loads `Uhome.php` it also *outputs* out out the **server-side code** of `Uhome.php` instead of running it. Please help me I have already researched online for answers but so far I haven't found any answers yet.

`settings.php`:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
    ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
  $ssl = 'https';
}
else {
  $ssl = 'http';


$app_url = ($ssl)
          . "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
          . (dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? "" : "/")
          . trim(str_replace("\\", "/", dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])), "/");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($)
    {
        var page_url = '<?php echo $app_url?>/';

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_load_home', function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            $(document).attr("title", 'Home');
            $(document).find('meta[name=description]').attr('content', data.description);

            window.history.pushState("", "", page_url);
            $(document).find('#sets-main').html(" ");
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_load_screen', function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var call_type = $(this).attr('call_type');

            $.getJSON(page_url+'ajax.php', {call_type: call_type}, function(data, textStatus, xhr)
            {

                $(document).attr("title", data.title);
                $(document).find('meta[name=description]').attr('content', data.description);

                $(document).find('#sets-main').html(data.data);

                window.history.pushState("", "", page_url+data.url);
            });
        });


    });
    </script>



<div class="NaV-SIdEbR">
  <div class="sets">
    <h1 class="seTinit">SETTINGS</h1>
  </div>
  <hr class="sets-dIvder">
  <div class="seTS-SiDe">
    <div class="seTs-main-nav">
      <div class="sets-Cont main">
        <a class="here" href="#home" style="color: #fffff">General</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sets-Cont">
        <a href="#news">Profile</a>
      </div class="sets-Cont">
      <div class="sets-Cont">
        <a href="#contact">Privacy</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sets-Cont">
        <a href="#about">Notifications</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="sets-dIvder-2">
    <div class="seTs-other">
      <div class="sets-Cont">
        <a class="here btn btn-info btn_load_screen" call_type="./../Uhome" href="./../Uhome" style="color: #fffff">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sets-Cont">
        <a href="#news">Search</a>
      </div class="sets-Cont">
      <div class="sets-Cont">
        <a href="./../v?i=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" class="here btn btn-info btn_load_screen" call_type="./../v?i=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php } ?>
```

`ajax.php`:

```
<?php

function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

if(isset($_GET['call_type']))
{
    $call_type = $_GET['call_type'];

    if($call_type == "jquery")
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status'=>'success',
            'title'=> 'jQuery Page',
            'description' => 'jQuery description',
            'url' => $call_type.'.php',
            'data'=>'This is <strong>jQuery</strong> data coming from ajax url'
        ));
    }
    else if($call_type == "php")
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status'=>'success',
            'title'=> 'PHP Page',
            'description' => 'PHP description',
            'url' => $call_type.'.php',
            'data'=>'This is <strong>PHP</strong> data coming from ajax url'
        ));
    }
    else if($call_type == "./../Uhome")
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status'=>'success',
            'title'=> 'Home Page',
            'description' => 'Home description',
            'url' => $call_type.'.php',
            'data'=>file_get_contents('./../Uhome.php'),
        ));
    }
    else if($call_type == "./../v?i=".$_SESSION['id'])
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status'=>'success',
            'title'=> 'Invoice receipt Page',
            'description' => 'Invoice receipt description',
            'url' => $call_type.'.php',
            'data'=>url_get_contents('../v?i='.$_SESSION['id']),
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the CSS for the site so you can understand it clearly:

```
:root {
  --main-font: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f100;
} 

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}

#progress {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2147483647;
  top: 0;
  left: -6px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #5365ff;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
#progress.done {
  opacity: 0
}
#progress dd {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 20px;
  right: 0;
  clip: rect(-6px,22px,14px,10px)
}
#progress dt {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 180px;
  right: -80px;
  clip: rect(-6px,90px,14px,-6px)
}

.main-container {
  top: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 350px;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-right:10px ;
}

input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"] {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"] {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 3px solid #555;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
  border: 3px solid #555;
}


/*Responsivnes*/

@media screen and (max-width: 656px) {
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="email"],
  input[type="number"] {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 469px) {
  .main-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Main */

.NaV-SIdEbR {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
}

.seTinit {
  position: relative;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  left: 30px;
  top: 05px;
}

.sets-dIvder {
  position: relative;
  color: #C4C4C4;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.seTS-SiDe {
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  font-size: 26px;
  position: relative;
}

.here {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.seTs-main-nav a {
  left: 30px;
  font-family: inherit;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.710);
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.sets-Cont {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.sets-Cont:hover {
  background-color: #3232328f;
}

.main {
  background-color: #2b2b2b8f;
}

.sets-dIvder-2 {
  position: relative;
  color: #C4C4C4;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.seTs-other a {
  left: 30px;
  font-family: inherit;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.710);
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.sets-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 300px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  height: 98vh;
}

.sets-gen {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 98vh;
}

.seTs-Main-top-h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seTs-top-divider {
  position: absolute;
  color: #C4C4C4;
  width: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Here is a picture of the page when I try to output `Uhome.php`:
[image]

Note that the settings page and `Uhome.php` are not in the same directory.

Help is appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you sure all of this code is necessary to reproduce the problem as a [mcve]? What does CSS have to do with this? Thanks.

Comment: The CSS is so that you can understand the page and navigate easily.

Comment: But if you want I can remove it as you desire.

Comment: Even then, there's still tons of probably irrelevant noise in the code. It seems all you need is a php file, jQuery to make a GET request and inject the content, maybe 20-40 lines total. That said, the problem seems fairly obvious: `file_get_contents('./../Uhome.php')` reads a PHP file which is returned as the payload, so there's no chance for PHP to actually preprocess anything and generate the HTML -- it's just sending it as plain text to the front end where it's set as `.html()`. The design seems pretty brittle, suggesting an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: Ok sure, I can modify the post.

Comment: How will I then output the data and run it?

Comment: You haven't really explained what goal all of this is supposed to achieve. You could pre-process the .php, then send the resulting HTML in your response, which is fully parsed and ready for `.html()`, but it's probably not the best way to do whatever application feature you're trying to implement.

Comment: My goal is to output `Uhome.php` on the settings page. So it asynchronously loads the page

Comment: Sure, I understand that, of course. But why did you choose to design the site like this? It's a very bizarre design choice, to say the least: `if($call_type == "jquery") ...`. Why not write a JSON API for a SPA? You seem to have presupposed that your design Y (returning .php files asynchronously) is the best solution to X (building a site with async page loads). Sure, people can help you solve Y (run PHP on the .php file, then send it), but that should send off all kinds of red flags, when there is probably a better solution to original problem X.

Comment: Thank you, I will try a JSON API

Comment: Well I'm not saying that's _definitely_ the best way. I'm trying to start a conversation about what you're trying to do so I can then understand what your needs and goals are for the site, and _then_ make a recommendation, or at least gain insight into why you chose to do things as you're doing here.

Comment: This website I am trying to do is a kind of a social networking site wherein people can post and socialize with other people but for games.